# React axios post request to wcf web service

Tags: reactjs, api, class, object, wcf

I am trying to post data from a react application to a wcf service class. Its a simple object with just name age and gender. The service is being called from the react app but with no data. If I use get request and parameter passing the data is passing to the service but I want to use post request. Is it necessary to match the field names as in the wcf service class.

For testing purpose in react component I am using this code

```
const headers = {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          }

    const puser = {
      Name:'Test',
      Age:'23',
      Gender:'F',
    }
    axios.post('http://localhost:3292/myService.svc/adduser',{headers:headers}, puser)
    .then(res=> {
      console.log(res.data)
    })
```

in wcf service the class code is

```
public class UserClass
    {

        string name;
        int age;
        string gender;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }

            set
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }

        public int Age
        {
            get
            {
                return age;
            }

            set
            {
                age = value;
            }
        }

        public string Gender
        {
            get
            {
                return gender;
            }

            set
            {
                gender = value;
            }
        }
}
```

and in service call

```
public string AddUser(List<User> U)
        {
            UserClass usr = new UserClass();
        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: You used wrong params position. `body data` should be 2nd param and `config` should be 3rd param. This is axios.post signature `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`

Comment: Your service expects an array of user but you send a user object.

Comment: Tried to switch the headers with data and also tried to make an array of the object and transfer it but still no data is received in the backend service.

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Axios post method expects `data` as second argument. Try to swap `puser` with `{headers}`.
https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config

Comment: tried it but still the data is not received in the service

Answer (score 0):

Do not add header in axios.post, code should look like this:

```
    const puser = {
      Name:'Test',
      Age:'23',
      Gender:'F',
    }
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/AddUser', puser)
    .then(res=> {
      console.log(res.data)
    })
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

**UPDATE:**

Set header in Postman:

[image]

Axios.post can also set the header like the following:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8000/AddUser',{ Name:'Test',
  Age:'2311',
  Gender:'FF'}, {headers: {
       'content-type': 'application/json'
    }})
.then(res=> {
  console.log(res.data)
})
```

**Here is my project:**

Program.cs:

```
using Demo_rest_ConsoleApp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp71
{
    public class User
    {

        string name;
        int age;
        string gender;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }

            set
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }

        public int Age
        {
            get
            {
                return age;
            }

            set
            {
                age = value;
            }
        }

        public string Gender
        {
            get
            {
                return gender;
            }

            set
            {
                gender = value;
            }
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    [CustContractBehavior]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string EchoWithGet(string s);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        string EchoWithPost(string s);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string AddUser(User U);
       
    }
    public class Service : IService
    {
        public string AddUser(User U)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(U.Age);
            Console.WriteLine(U.Gender);
            Console.WriteLine(U.Name);
            return "success";
        }

        public string EchoWithGet(string s)
        {
            return "You said " + s;
        }

        public string EchoWithPost(string s)
        {
            return "You said " + s;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("http://localhost:8000/"));
                ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
            ep.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior() { HelpEnabled=true});
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Open");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Soap.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;

namespace Demo_rest_ConsoleApp
{
    public class ServerMessageLogger : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
       
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(request);
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {

            WebOperationContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;
            ctx.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
            if (ctx.IncomingRequest.Method == "OPTIONS")
            {
               ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
                ctx.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
                ctx.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");

            }


        }
    }
    public class ClientMessageLogger : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {

        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class CustContractBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior, IContractBehaviorAttribute
    {
        public Type TargetContract => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new ClientMessageLogger());
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
        {
            dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new ServerMessageLogger());
        }

        public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            return;
        }
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: the postman is showing this error. The exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. I tried JSON.stringify but its not working.

Comment: no its not working. I hope there is no change in wcf because same service is working with a angular app. There must be something wrong in sending the data from react app.

Comment: I posted my project, you can refer to it, it can be accessed normally.